# Every quasicharacter of an open subgroup extends to a quasicharacter of the group

Tags: general-topology, topological-groups, characters, locally-compact-groups

Let $H$ be an open subgroup of a locally compact Hausdorff abelian group $G$.  Assume that $G/H$ is a finitely generated abelian group.  Let $\chi: H \rightarrow \mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ be a continuous homomorphism.  Does $\chi$ extend to a continuous homomorphism into $\mathbb{C}^{\ast}$ defined on all of $G$?

If $\chi$ maps $H$ into the circle $S^1$, then $\chi$ does extend to a continuous homomorphism on all of $G$, also mapping into $S^1$.  This follows from Pontryagin duality, and in fact this is true when $H$ is a closed, not necessarily open subgroup, and with no assumption about $G/H$.

Comment: An answer here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/293665/every-quasicharacter-of-an-open-subgroup-extends-to-a-quasicharacter-on-the-whol